# Como deve terminar corretamente essas variáveis sem ter chance de memory leak?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Qual a maneira correta de usar o `free()` nesse caso, sendo que `ls_options` conterá vários `ls_buffer_send`?

```
char **ls_options = (char**) malloc (200*sizeof(char));
char *ls_buffer_send = (char*) malloc (350*sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que a alocação está do jeito que precisa mesmo, não tem porque complicar, basta usar um `free()` simples:

```
free(ls_options);
free(ls_buffer_send);
```

Aproveita e simplifica a alocação:

```
char **ls_options = malloc(200);
char *ls_buffer_send = malloc(350);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocFree.c).

Evita até alguns problemas.

Comment: Tenho a impressão de que usar o free dessa forma (direto no vetor de ponteiros) todas as referencias vão ser perdidas. Isso não acabaria gerando o memory leak?

Comment: Que referências?

Comment: `ls_options` não é um array com 200 "referencias" para `char *`? Ou seja, 200 ponteiros para string?

Comment: Eu não vi isso nesse código. Eu vi 200 caracteres. Eu fiz a ressalva que a resposta é baseada no que ele postou. Se o código faz outras coisas além disto aí pode ser que tenha que fazer outras coisas. Note que ele está alocando caracteres, não ponteiros.

Comment: Bom, `char *` é um vetor de caracteres, uma string. `char **` é um vetor para strings. Se apagar o vetor de string todas as strings ainda continuarão alocadas certo?

Comment: O código está alocando 200 bytes, só isso, se ele vai usar isso de formas criativas eu não sei, mas é a única coisa que está fazendo. E o ponteiro onde essa alocação ocorreu será jogado em `ls_options`. O código não faz nada a mais.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43097/discussion-between-pilati-and-bigown).

Answer (score 1):

Percorrer todo o vetor liberando a memória para cada elemento ativo.

Como está declarando um tamanho fixo para a varável deverá ser feito mais ou menos assim:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<200; i++){
    if(ls_options[i] != NULL){
        free(ls_options[i]);
    }
}
free(ls_options);
```

Mas para isso funcionar corretamente todos os elementos devem ser setados como `NULL` na inicialização da `ls_options`